# iptables port forwarding

Tags: linux, iptables, tcp, port-forwarding

I have a CentOS server with Java/J2EE(Tomcat) installed on TCP port 8080.
I have two interfaces, eth0 and lo.

I need to forward all incoming connection on TCP port 80 to 8080.

I tried doing the following which works:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to x.x.x.x:8080
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW --dport 8080 -i eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

where x.x.x.x is the ip associated to the eth0 interface.

This appears to also open port 8080 to the outside world, which I don't want to do. I only want port 80 exposed to the outside world, forwarding all traffic to 8080.

Any help would be appreciated.

Update : The iptables -L looks like below

```
[root@server admin]# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ssh 
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:http 

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
[root@server admin]#
```

iptables -t nat --list looks like below

```
[root@server admin]# iptables -t nat --list
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:http to:x.x.x.x:8080 

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
[root@server admin]# ^C
```

Comment: Why not configure tomcat to listen on port 80? Or use apache/nginx as a reverse proxy?

Answer (score 1):

I posted a comment suggesting to set tomcat to listen on 80 or to use apache/nginx as a reverse proxy, which is what I think you should really be doing. But for posterity I will also answer your `iptables` question.

The problem is that what you're doing isn't DNAT, it's port redirection. Instead of `-j DNAT` you need `-j REDIRECT`.

E.g.:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the iptables backwards. The `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW --dport 8080 -i eth0 -j ACCEPT` explicity opens the port to the world. What you need is change the `ACCEPT` for `DROP`, then the port will only accept new connections to 80 but not to 8080.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW --dport 8080 -i eth0 -j DROP
```

Comment: Sorry, your solution doens't work. Would any more information help you provide me a better answer?

Comment: Did you cleared your iptables before adding the rule? `sudo iptables -F`?

Comment: Yes, cleared everything like in this wiki http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Network/IPTables.

Comment: Could you edit the question and add how `sudo iptables -L` looks like?